# In each sublist, replace the value in the right part by the value in the left part

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following nested list

```
{{a,1/x},{b,2x},{c,Sqrt[x]},{d,1-1/x}}
```

I'd like to come up with the same list where the variable $x$ is systematically replaced by the other element present in the same sublist. Here is the list I am trying to create

```
{{a,1/a},{b,2b},{c,Sqrt[c]},{d,1-1/d}}
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = {{a, 1/x}, {b, 2 x}, {c, Sqrt[x]}, {d, 1 - 1/x}}

{#1, #2 /. x -> #1} & @@@ lst
(* {{a, 1/a}, {b, 2 b}, {c, Sqrt[c]}, {d, 1 - 1/d}} *)
```

or

```
lst /. {a_, b_} :> {a, b /. x -> a}
 (* {{a, 1/a}, {b, 2 b}, {c, Sqrt[c]}, {d, 1 - 1/d}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MapThread[{#1, #2 /. x -> #1} & , Transpose@lst]
```

> {{a, 1/a}, {b, 2 b}, {c, Sqrt[c]}, {d, 1 - 1/d}}